# Spring/Tomcat timeout - mail jndi issue?

Tags: spring, tomcat, timeout, jndi

I'm trying to run an application using the Spring/Tomcat. There are a number of JNDI lookups, including one to a JDBC database and another to a mail service. These are configured in server.xml. That appears to work fine in Ubuntu, but on Windows 7, I need to set up "resource-link" tags in META-INF/context.xml to point to the resources and environment variables in server.xml.

I'm currently getting this list of errors when I attempt to run it;

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.3.1
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\javamail.providers (The system cannot find the file specified)
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\javamail.address.map (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I'm not completely sure if this is what's causing the server to timeout, since at one point I did have it running, even with these messages. Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: When do you get the server timeout? why do you think it is related? do you have any errors in the catalina log file?

Comment: The server timeout comes after the server states it's actually started. So, my feeling is that the errors shown are probably not related. I actually had it working at one point, by moving the resource and environment declarations to META-INF/context.xml. So, it's probably resource related. Catalina.out shows the same messages as the console.

Comment: It's running again - not sure what made the difference. I replaced the server.xml with one from another application that worked, only replacing the host.